# Using Cyclic Barrier to ensure 3 thread will run after each other

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, cyclicbarrier

By using , wait/notify or join or  2 countdownlatch I can make 3 threads to run in sequence.

How can similar be achieved through cyclic barrier?

Comment: That’s not the purpose of a cyclic barrier. Well, actually, it’s not even the purpose of threads “to run in sequence”. Why do you need a 3rd solution to your problem when you already have two?